# How do I get CMake to recognize I have QT5 installed? (building vktraceviewer)

Tags: linux, cmake, qt5, vulkan

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with the internals of CMake.

---

I downloaded Vulkan Tools via git (https://github.com/LunarG/VulkanTools.git)

Following the instructions in [BUILD.md](https://github.com/LunarG/VulkanTools/blob/master/BUILD.md), I use:

```
cmake -H. -Bdbuild -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

Which gives me:

```
WARNING: Qt5 dev libraries not found, vktraceviewer will not be built.
   To enable build of vktraceviewer, install package qt5-default.
```

I've installed qt5-default.
Checking through the CMake files I see it fails on [vktrace/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/LunarG/VulkanTools/blob/master/vktrace/CMakeLists.txt) line 572:

```
if (NOT Qt5_FOUND)
```

Grepping Qt5_FOUND, I don't see it being set anywhere, and I'm not getting much success via Google. I assume it's set from somewhere externally, so I'm thinking the issue is probably not with VulkanTools.

What is my next step here? Where is the issue likely to be? CMake? VulkanTools? QT5? Xubuntu?

---

Specs (if relevant):

- OS: Xubuntu 17.10.
- GFX: Radeon RX 480 (mesa drivers).

Comment: Condition `NOT Qt5_FOUND` means that QT5 (libraries and/or include files) have not been found. After installing `qt5-default`, have you tried to clean build directory (`dbuild` in your case)? So CMake will retry an attempt to find a library.

Comment: Yes, I have deleted dbuild and rebuilt, no change.

Comment: Just doing a full clean redownload and reinstall.

Comment: Problem still exists on a clean redownload :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by a missing Qt5 component, or rather, a missing config file, which is installed as part of the component development package. [If you look at the line where Qt5 is imported, you'll see:](https://github.com/LunarG/VulkanTools/blob/master/vktrace/CMakeLists.txt#L571)

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets Gui Core Svg QUIET)
```

`Widgets`, `Gui` and `Core` seems to be installed per default, so in your case, installing `libqt5svg5-dev` should solve this problem (note the `-dev` suffix). If this does not solve your problem, try removing the `QUIET` modifier from the `find_package()` call to see the error message and hopefully the offending component (I assume you have write-access to the `CMakeLists.txt` file).

If you are unable or don't want to modify `vktrace/CMakeLists.txt`, you can test for these Qt5 components by either checking `Qt5<component>_FOUND`, i.e. `Qt5Svg_FOUND` or, if you want to take a step further, inspecting their respective `Config`-module. Simply create a new `CMakeLists.txt` somewhere, paste the following then run `cmake` in the same directory.

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets Gui Core Svg)

message("config for Widgets: '${Qt5Widgets_CONFIG}'")
message("config for Gui: '${Qt5Gui_CONFIG}'")
message("config for Core: '${Qt5Core_CONFIG}'")
message("config for Svg: '${Qt5Svg_CONFIG}'")
```

The output should be similar to:

```
config for Widgets: '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake'
config for Gui: '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake'
config for Core: '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake'
config for Svg: '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Svg/Qt5SvgConfig.cmake'
```

An empty path means that `CMake` could not find a config-module for this component, which probably means it isn't installed.

Comment: Solved - It was libqt5svg5-dev, thanks. (There are so many qt5 packages that I didn't want to install everything).